# reCaptcha Widget using PHP/Curl

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I'm looking to build a small script that can load reCaptcha images from another website.
Seeing as the reCaptcha widget works using Javascript, is there anyway for one to capture the image generated using CURL?

Comment: Capturing the image is one thing, but how do you want to validate the response?

Comment: Fetching somebody elses captcha, hey! You're not attempting to make human spamming more efficient are you? http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2006/nov/23/comment.comment2

Answer (score 1):

First you have to detail what exactly you want to do a bit more. What is this other website you're getting the reCaptcha from?

Technically, reCaptcha tokens are only valid on the domain that they're registered for. The reasons why are detailed here

> **Signing up for a reCAPTCHA Key**
>
> In order to use reCAPTCHA, you need a
> public/private API key pair. This key
> pair helps to prevent an attack where
> somebody hosts a reCAPTCHA on their
> website, collects answers from their
> visitors and submits the answers to
> your site. You can sign up for a key
> on the reCAPTCHA Administration
> Portal.
>
> Key Scope Your reCAPTCHA token is
> valid only at the domain you sign up
> for and any subdomains (due to the
> potential attack mentioned above).
> Some users require keys for multiple
> sites, for example, a development
> server and a production server or
> simply multiple sites hosted on the
> same server. Three techniques can be
> used to work around this:
>
> If one of your servers is "localhost"
> or "127.0.0.1", reCAPTCHA will not
> enforce the same-domain rule. Just use
> the same key as for the production
> server. Generate a key for a broader
> scope. For example, if your
> application is a.example.com and your
> test server is test.corp.example.com,
> generate a key for example.com.
> Generate a different key for each
> domain.

source : http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/

This sounds like what you're trying to do, is it your server?